# Pythonic way to do `if x in y where x.attr == val`?

Tags: python

I have a class that represents a polynomial as a collection of terms where each term has a coefficient and an exponent. I am working on the `__add__` method of the class and I am wondering what the most effective way to do something like:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    new_terms = []
    for term in self.terms:
        if there is a term in other with an exponent == term.exponent
            new_terms.append(Term(term.coef + other_term.coef, term.exponent))
```

It strikes me that I'm looking for something such as:

```
if x in y where x.attr == val
```

Or in my specific case:

```
if x in other where x.exponent == term.exponent
```

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I think you want `[x for x in  y if x.attr == val]`, or `next(the same expression)` for just the first such value.

Comment: @tobias_k, could you clarify how that would be used?

Comment: The `__add__` operator should not mutate the `self` instance. And don't forget, if a term is not present in A but is present in B, then it should be present in A+B as well. BTW I assumed that your `terms` variable came from `self.terms`

Comment: If you do sparse polynomials, it might be betterto use a `dict` to store the  coefficients. And then, `2*x**2 + (-2)*x**2` should be simplified from `0*x**2` to simply `0`

Comment: @hege_hegedus does `__add__` then simply return the addition of self and other without necessarily mutating self? Also good catch on the self.

Comment: you have to build a new instance of your type and return it explicitly.

Comment: @hege_hegedus for the dictionary implementation you would be using the exponents as the keys and storing the coefficient? Also thanks for your help on `__add__`.

Comment: As for a dense implementation I would use an array of coefficients, which is a dense map of exponents to coefficients. For a sparse implementation a dict of exponent -> coefficient should be fine.

Comment: @hege_hegedus dense vs sparse clarification?

Comment: As hege_hegedus says, a dict is good if you expect the collection of exponents to be sparse. But that's pretty unusual in your typical polynomial, where the collection of exponents is usually quite dense, and generally running from zero up to some smallish number, and so can easily be handled by a list of coefficients with the exponent as the list index. Sure, dict lookup is faster than list lookup for large collections, but lists can be faster (& smaller) for small collections, since a dict has the overhead of maintaining & accessing a hash table.

Comment: By *dense* i mean `5*x**2+2*x**1+3*x**0` and by *sparse*: `5*x**90000*2*x**300+3*x**7000`. Your original implementation using an array of terms is a *sparse* implementation, but with lots of terms it could get slow, because of the linear searches for specific exponents.

Comment: Nick, I expect you'll mostly be working with polys like `x**6 + 2*x**4 + 3*x**3 + 2*x - 1`, etc, rather than  `x**635 + 3*x**204 + 3*x**103 + 2*x**37 + 5*x**4 +7`. In my first poly the collection of exponents is dense, in the second it is rather sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to filter your list before doing your contains check.  As tobias_k suggested, you can either build a new list, e.g.

```
[x for x in other if x.exponent == term.exponent]
```

This works directly in an `if` statement, because an empty list is `False`:

```
if [x for x in other if x.exponent == term.exponent]:
```

But this does some wasteful work, since it a) has to construct a new list and b) doesn't short-circuit once a result is found.  Better is to use the same syntax in a generator expression:

```
(True for x in other if x.exponent == term.exponent)
```

Which you can then similarly use in an `if` statement, but no wasteful work is done:

```
if next((True for x in other if x.exponent == term.exponent), False):
```

Comment: True about the generator expression, but using this just to check whether there _is_ such an element, and then having to search _again_to get that element, seems wasteful, too.

Comment: Agreed, you shouldn't need to use this pattern if you'll be doing anything with the values (you'd just loop over them if so); this is only necessary if you *only* want to test for existence.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `[x for x in y if x.attr == val]`, or use `next` with the same expression for just the first such value.

In your case, it could look something like this:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    for term in self.terms:
        for other_term in (x for x in other.terms 
                             if x.exponent == term.exponent):
            term.coefficient += other_term.coefficient
```

However, this will not work too well. First, `__add__` should not modify neither `self` nor `other` but instead create a new polynomial. Also, this will ignore any values from `other` that have a different exponent that any of the terms in `self`. And third, the performance is pretty lousy, as it loops the list of terms in `other` for each term in `self`, giving it quadratic complexity.

---

Instead, I suggest using a dictionary, mapping exponents in the term to their coefficient. In fact, you could probably just use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for that; it already implements `__add__` in the right way. Something like this:

```
class Poly:

    def __init__(self, counts):
        self.terms = collections.Counter(counts)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Poly(self.terms + other.terms)

    def __str__(self):
        return " + ".join("%dx^%d" % (c, x) for x, c in self.terms.items())
```

Example:

```
>>> Poly({2: 1, 1: 3, 0: 5}) + Poly({3: 1, 1: 2, 0: 3})
8x^0 + 5x^1 + 1x^2 + 1x^3
```